# Is this a legal quoted-printable encoding?

Tags: mime, mime-message, quoted-printable

Is this a legal quoted-printable encoding?

```
a ==
3D b
```

How about this one?

```
a = b
the second line
```

I wonder if = can occur without encoding, and an encoding such as =3D can be put on two lines. The RFC is ambiguous.

Comment: Question is ambiguous. Add more context to this question.

Answer (score 2):

#### In Quoted-Printable encoding, the `=` character MUST be encoded as `=3D`

Here is the relevant excerpt from [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7):

> Octets with decimal values of
> 33 through 60 inclusive, and 62 through 126, inclusive,
> MAY be represented as the US-ASCII characters which
> correspond to those octets (EXCLAMATION POINT through
> LESS THAN, and GREATER THAN through TILDE,
> respectively).

The `=` ASCII character has decimal code 61, which explains why this number is explicitly forbidden by the RFC. Therefore, both of your examples are not legal Quoted-Printable encodings. The following encoding *is* legal:

```
a =3D b
the second line
```